# Programming Quicksort Algorithm Q

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to write quicksort and understand the algorithm. I understand the 3 basic principles of quick sort

- The element a[i] is in its final place in the array for some i.
- None of the elements in a[l], a[i1] is greater than a[i].
- None of the elemtns in a[i+1],..., a[r] is less than a[i].

I think I'm missing something about this algorithm. Any guidance much appreciated.

My first question is l and r, those are the min and max of the array? or is it any place within the left and right side of the array.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void quicksort(int a[], int l , int r);
int partition(int a[], int l, int r);
void exchange(int a[], int i, int j);


int main()
{
 const int MAX_ARRAY = 9;
 // Quicksort
 // Array of integers
 int numArray[MAX_ARRAY] = {25,10,25,34,38,7,6,43,56};




 for ( int i = 0 ; i < MAX_ARRAY ; i++) 
 {
  cout << numArray[i] << endl;  
 }


 quicksort(numArray, 4, 7);
 // Call quicksort
 for ( int i = 0 ; i < MAX_ARRAY ; i++) 
 {
  cout << numArray[i]<< endl;  
 }


 system("pause");

 return 0;
}

void quicksort(int a[], int l , int r)
{
 // 
 if (r <= l) {return;} // The max position and least position are now overlapping
 int i = partition(a, l, r); // send the array and the two positions to partition
 // i gives me the next position
 quicksort(a,l,i-1); // sort left side
 quicksort(a,i+1,r); // sort right side
}

int partition(int a[], int l, int r) 
{
 //Declarations
 int i = l-1, j = r; int v = a[r];

 for(;;) // Infinite ForLoop
 {
  // go through till you find a value in the array that is less than v = our pivot
  while(a[++i] < v) ;
  while (v < a[--j]) if (j == 1) break; // THis condition is to go thorugh and check for a number that is larger than v then if j is not at 1 then we break
  if ( i >= j) break; // Overlap array
  exchange(a, i , j); // swap the values

 }
  exchange(a,i,j); // swap the values
  return i;
}

void exchange(int a[], int i, int j ) 
{
 int temp = a[i];
 a[i] = a[j];
 a[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: @Sam: Can't see how it wouldn't be. Any sane person is going to use `std::sort` for real code :P

Comment: @Billy But what if the professor is insane?

Comment: @muntoo: if it's not homework, then the sanity of any given professor doesn't really matter.

Comment: Either someone's insane... or no one is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My first question is l and r, those are the min and max of the array? or is it any place within the left and right side of the array.*
No, those are the left and right borders of the current sub-array being sorted. I have no idea why you invoke method with parameters `4` and `7`: it means none of the elements before 4-th or after 7-th will be sorted.

Answer (score -1):

first, `quicksort(numArray, 4, 7);` should be `quicksort(numArray, 0, 8);`

second, to make it a little bit faster, you can set a cutoff number like 10 on which you switch to insertion sort. Insertion sort is faster than quick sort for small input.

Comment: -1. The first part imparts no particular understanding. The second has nothing to do with quicksort (the OP's topic)